# "core i 5 intel Processor up to 3.1" how and where to verify

Tags: windows-7, laptop, intel-core-i5

I just bought an HP probook 450 system and on bill its written processor core i5 upto 3.1 but when i go in system properties in windows 7 it says 2.50 ghz.

Can anybody please tell me if there is any possibility that the processor can go to 3.1 (as written bill upto 3.1) or if it's not possible?

Update: So here is the exact CPU SPecs which i got by Speccy Application 
`Intel Core i5 3320M @ 2.60GHz Ivy Bridge 22nm Technology`

Comment: Please provide us the exact CPU you have in your laptop.  [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy) can be used to do this.  Once you do that Daniel can improve his answer to provide specifics with regards to your CPU.

Comment: According to ARK Intel, your turbo boost can actually reach 3.3 GHz. [Source](http://ark.intel.com/products/64896/Intel-Core-i5-3320M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_30-GHz)

Answer (score 7):

This is made possible by a feature called “[Intel Turbo Boost](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html)”:

> Intel® Turbo Boost Technology 2.0 automatically allows processor cores to run faster than the rated operating frequency if they’re operating below power, current, and temperature specification limits.
>
> Intel Turbo Boost Technology 2.0 is activated when the Operating System (OS) requests a frequency higher than the rated frequency of the processor.  Whether the processor enters into and the amount of time the processor spends in the Intel Turbo Boost Technology 2.0 state depends on the workload and operating environment.
>
> **Maximum turbo frequency indicates the highest possible frequency achievable when conditions allow the processor to enter turbo mode.** Intel Turbo Boost Technology frequency varies depending on workload, hardware, software and overall system configuration.
>
> Due to varying power characteristics, some parts with Intel Turbo Boost Technology 2.0 may not achieve maximum turbo frequencies when running heavy workloads and using multiple cores concurrently.

(Emphasis mine)

So yes, it is possible and the 3.1 GHz indicated is the maximum Turbo Boost speed.

Answer (score 4):

You have a Core i5 4200m. If you check the [specifications](http://ark.intel.com/products/76348/Intel-Core-i5-4200M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz), you can see that 2.5GHz is the normal speed and 3.1GHz is the maximum.

Comment: I have Intel Core i5 3320M @ 2.60GHz Ivy Bridge 22nm Technology. But even with this software I am not able to see speed upto 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7's system panel or it's task manager won't tell you the dynamic frequency, you'll need OCCT or cpu-z to see that.

http://www.ocbase.com/

http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Note that 3.1Ghz is the maximum frequency on 1 core. You should stuck at 2.7Ghz on 2 cores.